# multiprocessing value and lock

Tags: python

We need to write multiprocessing code for two functions, in one we enter the start and end values ** (for example 0 4) **, and enter the names ** (Alex Jenn Jack) **. The second function (set) prints the result. Arguments written inside the function are required. The arguments to the set (name, item, iter_stop, lock) function are all four, required. There should be two functions in the code.
The output should be the following:
*Alex 0
Jenn 1
Jack 2
Alex 3
Jenn 4*

Need to use Process, Lock, Value. There is code below, I was only able to implement sequential counter for one function. How to concatenate it with names and output it I cannot figure out.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock,Value

start = Value('I',0)

def set(name,item,iter_stop,lock):
    """
    Prints out the item that was passed in
    """
    with start.get_lock():
      start.value+=1
      print(start.value,name)
def start_g():
  start, game_stop = map(int, input().split()) 
  players = input().split()
  set

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    lst=['Alex', 'Jenn','Jack']
    for item in lst:
        p = Process(target=start_g, args=(item, lock))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```